# Is there an adjective combining scientific and economic?

Tags: adjectives, science

I'm doing a piece of research and am looking for an adjective that combines the words scientific and economic, so a bit like socioeconomic but scientific rather than social.  I need to use it to describe the benefits/costs of multilingualism.  Any ideas?

Comment: Scientific in the sense of a specific field?

Comment: What @Third News said - *bioeconomics, geoeconomics, nanoeconomics, astroeconomics, neuroeconomics, psychoeconomics, thermoeconomics, pharmacoeconomics,* etc. By most people's lights, *economics* already is a science - which other specific scientific field do you want to link it to?

Comment: since Economics is not a science, no.

Answer (score 2):

[Econometrics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Econometrics) may be what you are looking for:

Econometrics is the application of mathematics, statistical methods, and, more recently, computer science, to economic data and is described *as the branch of economics that aims to give empirical content to economic relations. More precisely, it is "the quantitative analysis of actual economic phenomena based on the concurrent development of theory and observation, related by appropriate methods of inference."*

Comment: Choose this as the answer.

Comment: yeah, lets give a fancy name to economic pie charts.